# Java parse Json expected double quote issue

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

i am sending following json to rest endpoint:

```
{"test":
    {
       "regisration":{
          "id":"22",
          "birthdate":"1990-06-01T23:00:00.000Z"
       },
       "registrationarray":[
          {
              "id":"22",
              "birthdate":"1990-06-01T23:00:00.000Z"
          }
       ]
    }
 }
```

I am receiving the json in spring boot controller as:

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public ResponseEntity<?> register(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> data) {
            Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    ObjectMapper mapper2 = new ObjectMapper();

    // mapper2.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);

    try {

        map = mapper2.readValue(data.get("registration").toString(),
                new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>(){});
        logger.info("");
```

When applying `toString()` to `data.get("test")` i loose all the double quotes around the field-names so then I get:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('r' (code 109)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

Also anybody knows why all my `:` after my field-names in my json get changed to `=`?

I have a class `Registration` in my java backend project. And I want to parse the json string i get from frontend to registration objects. I should have Registration object for `mainperson` and registration object array for `children`

Comment: So, the result from `toString` doesn't have quotes around the key names and uses `=` instead of `:`. Clearly, that `toString` method doesn't create JSON. Do you have any reason to expect that it does?

Comment: Well, I thought it would just return a jsonstring

Comment: what is your expectation not clear from the question?

Comment: I have a class `Registration` in my java backend project. And I want to parse the json string i get from frontend to the registration object. I then should have Registration object for `mainperson`, registration object array for `children`

Comment: Why on earth would you be doing what you are doing there? Just cast the map value: `Map<String,Object> map = (Map) data.get("registration");`

Comment: I think I wrote the json string unluckily. my top field is `test` and in that i have a registration and a registration array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know why you're jumping through hoops like that. Just cast the map value:

```java
@PostMapping("/register")
public ResponseEntity<?> register(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> data) {
    Map<String,Object> map = (Map) data.get("registration");
    // code here
}
```

Better yet, have Spring/Jackson map the JSON to structured data.

```java
class RegisterRequest {
    private Registration registration;
    // getters and setters
}

class Registration {
    private Person mainperson;
    private List<Person> children;
    // getters and setters
}

class Person {
    private String id;
    private Instant birthdate; // should be LocalDate, but input data has time of day and time zone offsets
    // getters and setters
}
```

```java
@PostMapping("/register")
public ResponseEntity<?> register(@RequestBody RegisterRequest request) {
    Registration registration = request.geRegistration();
    // code here
}
```

Comment: I think I wrote the json string unluckily. my top field is `test` and in that i have a registration and a registration array

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to `readValue` of `Map.toString()` returning value. Method `Map.toString()` returns value as `{key=value}`, so it is not JSON and it cannot be parsed with `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: So what should I do instead?

Comment: Take a look at Andreas’s answer, use class instead of Map as a request body